# Redirect all https://www.mydomain.com to https://mydomain.com using htaccess (2 SSL HOST in cpanel)

Tags: .htaccess

I need to redirect one domain `https://www.mydomain.com to https://mydomain.com.` I use this .htaccess and it not work for me.

Previously i have the ssl cert for `https://www.mydomain.com` and it was broke, we register the new ssl for the host `https://mydomain.com`

In the WHM there is only one ssl host but in the cpanel there are two hosts one is old `www.mydomain.com` and `mydomain.com` (Is this effect on the redirection?)

the .htaccess is below.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I am getting the security alert always while i type `https://www.mydomain.com`.

What the mistake that i did here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the difference between 2 & 3

Comment: I use {HTTPS_HOST} in 3rd

Answer (score -1):

> What is the mistake here ?

The mistake is that there *is* no `%{HTTPS_HOST}` variable. The `%{HTTP_HOST}` is the request header (Host) that's part of the HTTP protocol. You don't need the 3rd line, what you want to do is check whether or not the request was HTTPS using the `%{HTTPS}` variable like you're doing in the first condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ https://mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ https://mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply its great answer but I cannot redirect the "https://www.mydomain.com" to "https://mydomain.com" ohters are fine. The main issue here is, i had the ssl certificate "https://www.mydomain.com" because of server issue the ssl is break and newly install ssl in "http://mydomain.com". Is that be the issue ? What you say?